# How to eliminate a maximum value in a for loop to fulffil a certain criteria?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this data frame:`age <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
gender <- c("M","F")
df <- data.frame(age, gender)`

Creating this : `average <- df %>% group_by(gender) %>% summarise(average_age = mean(age))`

I obtain:

```
gender average_age
  F        6
  M        5
```

How can I iterate the age of Females and eliminate the maximum value in order to have an `average_age < 4`?
The reality is that I have a much bigger dataset and I cannot do this manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of iterating you can group by the gender and then sort by gender and age ascending. You can use the `cummean()` function to find the point where the average age for females `>= 4` and then filter out all of the female records from that point on.

```r
age <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
gender <- c("M","F")
df <- data.frame(age, gender)

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(gender) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(gender,age) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(CumAvgAge = cummean(age)) %>%
  dplyr::filter(!(gender == "F" & 
                CumAvgAge >= 4)) %>%
  dplyr::select(-CumAvgAge) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(average_age = mean(age))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  gender average_age
  <fct>        <dbl>
1 F                3
2 M                5
```

If you ultimately want the list of individual ages you can remove the last call to `summary()`:

```r
df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(gender) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(gender,age) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(CumAvgAge = cummean(age)) %>%
  dplyr::filter(!(gender == "F" & 
                CumAvgAge >= 4)) %>%
  dplyr::select(-CumAvgAge) 

# A tibble: 7 x 2
# Groups:   gender [2]
    age gender
  <dbl> <fct> 
1     2 F     
2     4 F     
3     1 M     
4     3 M     
5     5 M     
6     7 M     
7     9 M
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler answer with `dplyr` is to add a `filter()` function:

```
library(dplyr)
average <- df %>% group_by(gender) %>% 
     filter((gender == "F" & age <= 4) | gender == "M") %>% 
     summarise(average_age = mean(age))
average
```

...and the output:

```
average
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  gender average_age
  <fct>        <dbl>
1 F                3
2 M                5
>
```

Comment: OP said they want average age to be `< 4`. You are filtering out anyone with an actual age `< 4`, so your average will always be `< 4` but you may incorrectly eliminate observations `> 4` while the average is still `< 4`. For example if you had females `c(1,1,1,5)` you would eliminate the 5 year old even though they should all remain because the overage average is still `< 4`.

Comment: @Wil - thanks for the feedback. It begs the question of why one would eliminate some females with age > 4 while retaining others and still have a valid analysis, but that is outside the scope of the OP.

Comment: agreed, the reason why one would want to do this for their analysis is not clear.

Comment: It was just an example that I created quickly to transpose to another problem that I have regarding wind speeds and its characteristics.. sorry for not making sense but it was made in a rush